# Access dependencies in extension methods

Tags: c#

[image]

How can I access the *factory* property in MediaMuxer inside this MergeChannels extension method? is it possible?

```
public class MediaMuxer : IMediaMuxer
{
   protected readonly IProcessWorkerFactory factory;
   public MediaMuxer(IProcessWorkerFactory processFactory);
}
```

Comment: Please try to keep irrelevant tag soup to a minimum.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't access the `factory` field, because it's protected - it would only be accessible from a subclass of `MediaMuxer`, and extension methods can only be declared in static classes, so those can't be subclasses of `MediaMuxer`. (And even then, it's only accessible within an instance *of the subclass in which the accessing code is written* - not just any arbitrary `MediaMuxer`.)

Additionally, even if that were public, `muxer` is declared to be of type `IMediaMuxer`, not `MediaMuxer`, so you'll only have access to members declared in `IMediaMuxer`. So basically:

- If you can make it a public property in `IMediaMuxer`, that would do it
- Otherwise, make it a public property (rather than a field, if possible) in `MediaMuxer` and change your extension method's first parameter to be of type `MediaMuxer`.